# Drupal 8 Commerce Module Hook_Theme()

Tags: commerce, hooks

I'm working on a custom module that I want to hook into a custom commerce template.

Heres is the code inside of my custom module the returns the variable.

```
 /**
     * Implements hook_theme().
     * @param $existing
     * @param $type
     * @param $theme
     * @param $path
     * @return array
     */
    function my_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
        return [
              'commerce-product--full' => [
                'variables'=> array (
                    'key'=> "I'm a key.",
                ),
              ],
        ]
}
```

Inside of commerce-product--full, using kint(key), I get null as a response.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What function is that in?

Comment: I edited the question to show the function.

Comment: Sorry I don't know a hook named my_hook(). Can't help. Maybe someone else will know it.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing `hook_theme_registry_alter()` and see how that goes.

```
function mymodule_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
    $theme_registry['commerce_product__full']['path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/templates';
}
```

Your module presumably will have a folder named templates. And inside the folder you have a file called commerce-product--full.html.twig

Comment: Thank you but that wasn't it. I think it's directly related to the Commerce plugin.

Comment: @Jeremy you resolved it?

Comment: No. Still looking into Commerce docs and around the web for a solution.

Comment: My answer is actually messed up. Just realizing that. For context purposes how are you using that template? Inside a block? Or is it rendered for a given path?

Comment: It's a custom twig file that replaces the default commerce.html.twig.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `hook_theme_registry_alter()`. Let me see if I can do a code sample for you.

Answer (score 1):

So I did figure out the answer. It was a combination of turning dashes into underscores and using a preprocess function.

```
/**
     * Implements hook_theme().
     * @param $existing
     * @param $type
     * @param $theme
     * @param $path
     * @return array
     */
    function my_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
        return [
              'commerce_product__full' => [
                     'preprocess functions' => ['my_preprocess_function'],

              ],
        ]
}

function my_preprocess_function(&$variables) {
    $variables['slogan'] = "I'm a slogan!!";
}
```

Thanks for everyone's help.